# Remedy for dog digging in yard

Tags: dogs, behavior

His name is Lance. He’s a 15 pound Cheweenie and he loves to play and also dig holes in the backyard. We have no grass. What can we do to stop him from digging? I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: +1 I thought we would already have several answers to this.  If so I am not finding them.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, however we also have moles that create a mess of our backyard. Our Labrador Retriever digs some pretty big holes (1-2 feet in diameter and 1 foot deep) and often nearby or exactly on top of where old mole hills have been or currently exist.
My friend who is very knowledgeable about dogs (agility trains them), suggested I get a “kiddie pool” and fill it with sand. Thinking that if it’s more that the dog “wants/enjoys to dig” instead of “trying to find something”, it would give them an acceptable place to dig without destroying our yard.
I personally haven’t tried this yet, but it sounds like a great idea!